# Terraform OCI, how to prevent deletion of a core volume attached to compute?

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

How do you prevent the deletion of a core volume attached to the instance in OCI using Terraform?

Using Terraform v1.1.6, I noticed with the provider AWS you can enable `enable_deletion_protection`, but on OCI there is no such option, for example:

```
resource "oci_core_volume" "volume_1" {
  count               = 1
  availability_domain = data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ad_list.availability_domains[0]["name"]
  compartment_id      = "test"
  display_name        = "test_disk"
  size_in_gbs         = 50
  vpus_per_gb         = 10
}
```

I have looked at `lifecycle` events, but the [documentation for oci_core_volume](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/oci/latest/docs/resources/core_volume) has no examples of their usage on oci_core_volume

```
lifecycle {
```

}

I want to make sure that any updates to my "oci_core_instance" instance do not delete the "oci_core_volume" which they currectly do, instead updates should reattach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oci_core_volume` documentation does not give you an example because `lifecycle` events are meta-arguments and their usage is the same for every type of resource. You can find examples which do apply for all kind of resources in the `lifecycle` [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#prevent_destroy).

An example of usage would in your case would be:

```
resource "oci_core_volume" "volume_1" {
  count               = 1
  availability_domain = data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ad_list.availability_domains[0]["name"]
  compartment_id      = "test"
  display_name        = "test_disk"
  size_in_gbs         = 50
  vpus_per_gb         = 10

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Just keep in mind that `prevent_destroy` will throw an error whenever the resource is marked for destruction. You will still be able to destroy the resource manually from the outside.

Comment: Also, `prevent_destroy` cannot be overriden like a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by being overridden? `prevent_destroy` does not accept a variable, this does not work: `prevent_destroy = var.destroy`. Besides this, I'm not aware of any flags for the terraform plan, which will override lifecycle meta-arguments.

Comment: That’s what I mean by “cannot be”